# Bloquear sección de una pagina

Tags: javascript, html, css

en mi empresa me estan pidiendo bloquear una parte de la pagina, la pagina carga inicialmente así: [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero cuando le de click a la opción "Equipo Seadog" 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
se debe desbloquear la sección de la pagina la cual se encuentra en la parte inferior y bajaria automaticamente hasta esa parte de la pagina.

Este es el codigo de la pagina:

```
<div class="principal">
<div id="divHome" class="row">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-5">
                <h1 id="h1HomeTitle" class="lang" key="h1HomeTitle">Laboratorio estrategico</h1>
                <h4 class="lang" key="h4FHomeFirstText">
                    Diseñamos a través de las necesidades de <br> marca la mejor ruta 
                    para cumplir con sus <br> objetivos y alcanzar resultados.
                </h4>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-offset-4 col-4">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-dark prueba">Descubre cómo</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-1 ">
            </div>
            <div class="col-4 ">
                <?php
                echo $this->Html->image('ciclo-estrategia-seadog.png', array('alt' => 'Proceso', 'key' => 'imgProcess',
                    'class' => 'lang'));
                ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Esto iria al final de la pagina

```
 <div class="ensayo">
    <br>
    <br>
    <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
    Aqui iria el codigo donde estan los integrantes del equipo seadog, ya sean fotos o informacion de cada uno.Aqui iria el codigo donde estan los integrantes del equipo seadog, ya sean fotos o informacion de cada uno.Aqui iria el codigo donde estan los integrantes del equipo seadog, ya sean fotos o informacion de cada uno.Aqui iria el codigo donde estan los integrantes del equipo seadog, ya sean fotos o informacion de cada uno.Aqui iria el codigo donde estan los integrantes del equipo seadog, ya sean fotos o informacion de cada uno.
    Aqui iria el codigo donde estan los integrantes del equipo seadog, ya sean fotos o informacion de cada uno.
    Aqui iria el codigo donde estan los integrantes del equipo seadog, ya sean fotos o informacion de cada uno.
    Aqui iria el codigo donde estan los integrantes del equipo seadog, ya sean fotos o informacion de cada uno.
    Aqui iria el codigo donde estan los integrantes del equipo seadog, ya sean fotos o informacion de cada uno.
    Aqui iria el codigo donde estan los integrantes del equipo seadog, ya sean fotos o informacion de cada uno.
    Aqui iria el codigo donde estan los integrantes del equipo seadog, ya sean fotos o informacion de cada uno.
    Aqui iria el codigo donde estan los integrantes del equipo seadog, ya sean fotos o informacion de cada uno.
    Aqui iria el codigo donde estan los integrantes del equipo seadog, ya sean fotos o informacion de cada uno.
    Aqui iria el codigo donde estan los integrantes del equipo seadog, ya sean fotos o informacion de cada uno.
    Aqui iria el codigo donde estan los integrantes del equipo seadog, ya sean fotos o informacion de cada uno.
    Aqui iria el codigo donde estan los integrantes del equipo seadog, ya sean fotos o informacion de cada uno.
    Aqui iria el codigo donde estan los integrantes del equipo seadog, ya sean fotos o informacion de cada uno.
    Aqui iria el codigo donde estan los integrantes del equipo seadog, ya sean fotos o informacion de cada uno. 
</div>
```

Comment: Ese cuadrado fucsia es el menú desplegable que sale al clickear el botón hamburguesa?

Comment: "Se debe desbloquear la sección de la pagina la cual se encuentra en la parte inferior y bajaria automaticamente hasta esa parte de la pagina"

Claro, claro, eso... explicate mejor plz

Comment: @amenadiel asi es.

Comment: @FederHico esta la pagina como la ves ahí en la primer foto. y no debe dejar usar los scroll, que solo se pueda ver lo que esta en el div principal. y al darle click a "Equipo Seadog" debe bajar hasta el div ensayo, el cual su codigo no quedo, ya lo pego. Esta documentado ya que la pagina esta en producción eso no se debe ver.

Answer (score 2):

Puedes esconder el `div` y mostrarlo cuando se de click en el enlace que tu elijas y luego hacer scroll hasta el `div` deseado.

Un ejemplo funcional (los estilos los agregué para el ejemplo), en el javascript adaptas tus elementos:

```js
$('.show-more').on('click', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();

  // Tomamos una referencia del elemento a mostrar
  var $ensayo = $('.ensayo');

  // Quitamos la clase d-none que lo mantiene oculto
  $ensayo.removeClass('d-none');

  // Hacemos scroll al div deseado
  $('html,body').animate({
    scrollTop: $ensayo.offset().top
  }, 'slow');
});
```

```css
.principal {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-height: 100vh;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="principal bg-success text-white text-center">
  <h1>Soy lo único por ahora</h1>
  <a href="#" class="text-white show-more">Muestrame más...</a>
</div>
<div class="ensayo d-none">
  <div class="p-5">
    <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
      dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</h3>
  </div>
</div>
```